# python web scraping returns no value

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

Im using the script Below to capture data from a web page. The Data Im after is actually generated by ajax. Hence I dont get any results when finding a particular element on a page.
The element Im after loads in a medium like firebug but doesnt in "view source" in a Browser which should be normal.
Manually loading the XHR post and response URLs gives me an error. Ive also noticed that the post and response urls have a random generated id appended at the end.
Im using python 3.4.3 How do I get around this ? Thanks

```
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
import re

htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com")

htmltext = htmlfile.read()

regex = (b'(<span id="one">.+?</span>)')
pattern = re.compile(regex)

Data = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print (Data)
```

Comment: More information would help us help you.  When you say you get an error when manually ,loading the XHR post and response, what error do you get?   Is it possible to provide the actual URL you are scraping and the actual XHR post and response URLs?

Comment: Both the post and response URLs have have the same id and when loaded the page loads with a message that reads "Bad".

Comment: I tried some web scraping today from aYouTube dev feed - but it errored out because they changed their API and the URL I was using was no longer valid - a typical reason for a web scraping failure. Another typical reason is that the owners of the URL implemented an authorization requirement - which YouTube did as well. Regarding the error: What is its HTTP response code?  Find out then look it up in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Have you looked into the requests library? your question is slightly vague, but requests may help significantly if you need to make make posts and pass parameters to URLs.  http://docs.python-requests.org

Comment: An HTTP Request gives me a "200" on the post and return URLs.